Calculus criterion of strict convexity?
Suppose function $f\left(x\right)$ is defined on a closed interval $\left[a, b\right]$. Is "$f\left(x\right)$ is twice differentiable on $\left(a,b\right)$ and $f''\left(x\right)>0$ on $\left(a, b\right)$" sufficient for $f$ being strictly convex on $\left[a,b\right]$? (I want $f\left(\lambda a+\left(1-\lambda\right)b\right)<\lambda f\left(a\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)f\left(b\right)$, for all $\lambda \in \left(0,1\right)$) (I think the answer is no because I can arbitrarily change the function value at $a$ and $b$ without violating these conditions.) Do we need the additional condition that "the second order right derivative exists at $a$ and is strictly positive, and the second order left derivative exists at $b$ is strictly positive"? Is it possible to make the additional condition weaker?

Yes, $f(a)$ can be any real number.

Continuity of $f$ at $a$ from the right and at $b$ from the left will be sufficient. The existence of derivatives at $a$ and $b$ is superfluous.
Indeed, let $z_0=\lambda a+(1-\lambda) b$
$$
T(x)=f(x)-[f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(x-z_0)].
$$
Then $T(z_0)=0$ and $T'(x)=f'(x)-f'(z_0)$. Moreover, $T'(z_0)=0$ and $\frac{d}{dx} T'(x)>0$ for $x\in (0,b)$ so $T'(x)$ is strictly increasing, implying $T'(x)>0$ for $x>z_0$ and $T'(x)<0$ for $x<z_0$.
Consequently, as $b>z_0$, $T(b)>T(z_0)$ (since $T'>0$ and $T$ is strictly increasing for $x\in(z_0,b)$) as well as $T(a)>T(z_0)$ (since $T'<0$ and $T$ is strictly decreasing for $x\in(a,z_0)$).
So
$$
\lambda T(a)+(1-\Lambda)T(b)>T(z_0)=0
$$
and on the other hand
$$
\lambda T(a)+(1-\lambda)T(b)=\lambda f(a)+(1-\lambda)f(b)
-[f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b-z_0)]
=\lambda f(a)+(1-\lambda)f(b)
-f(z_0).
$$

Could you please elaborate on it? I can only derive weak concavity: $f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b)>\lambda f(a+\varepsilon)+(1-\lambda) f(b-\varepsilon)\Rightarrow f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b) \geqslant \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\lambda f(a+\varepsilon)+(1-\lambda) f(b-\varepsilon)=\lambda f(a)+(1-\lambda) f(b)$.

Please see above.

I understand for all $x\in (z_0,b)$, $T(x)>T(z_0)$. But why then $T(b)>T(z_0)$? Continuity at $b$ only implies $T(b) \geqslant T(z_0)$.

Since $z_0<b$, there is a point $z_1$ such that $z_0<z_1<b$.  Because of strict monotonicity $T(z_1)>T(z_0)$. And trivially $T(b)\ge T(z_1)$.
